# Prefetching manytomany field doesn't change execution speed

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```
m = MyModel.objects.all().only("colA", "colB").prefetch_related("manyToManyField")

for mm in m:
    print(mm.id)
    list(mm.manyToManyField.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

This code takes too long to execute.

This takes virtually no time (no reference to manyToManyField in loop):

```
m = MyModel.objects.all().only("colA", "colB").prefetch_related("manyToManyField")

for mm in m:
    print(mm.id)
```

And this takes nearly the **exact** same time as the first

```
m = MyModel.objects.all().only("colA", "colB")

for mm in m:
    print(mm.id)
    list(mm.manyToManyField.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

This makes me think that `.prefetch_related("manyToManyField")` is useless and it is not actually fetching anything and `list(mm.manyToManyField.values_list('id', flat=True))` hits the database for every cycle.

Why is this and how can I force to prefetch from a manytomany field?

I've tried to remove `list()` but then `mm.manyToManyField.all().values_list` gives me a queryset that is not JSON serializable (no, I don't want to install rest framework).

Also tried `list(mm.manyToManyField.all().values_list)` with `list()`:  still goes crazy slow.

Comment: By using `.values_list`, you will indeed not boost performance, since all queries different from `.all()` will again hit the database.

Comment: also tried list(manyToManyField.all().values_list(...)), still same problem. Updating the question right now...

Comment: of course, since again, you made a *different* query than the one you `.prefetch_related(..)` and therefore it will have to do another query to the database.

Comment: How is that a different query? I'm querying the mm object, that should have the m2m field preloaded.

Comment: Oh, you mean I should call only .all() and then manually do the values list, rather than use the Django function to do the list?

Comment: indeed. You can furthermore use `Prefetch` objects, to for example prefetch a filtered variant already, but all variants that do not match the ones prefetched, will result in new queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this and how can I force to prefetch from a manytomany field?

The reason this happens is because you make a different query than the `manyToManyField.all()`, and thus that one is *not* performed. Imagine that you would `myManyToManyField.filter(some_col=some_val)`, then it will hit the database as well, since a database is optimized to filter effectively.

If you would fetch the values, with:

```
# no extra query

for mm in m:
    print(list(mm.manyToManyField.all()))
```

or if you want to print the primary keys, you can just fetch these with list comprehension for example:

```
# no extra query

for mm in m:
    print([k.id for k in mm.manyToManyField.all()])
```

it will not make an additional query, since you already loaded that one with the `.prefetch_related('manyToManyField')`, but all variants, like filtering, annotating, etc. are not loaded.

You can however pass arbitrary querysets to prefetch with [**`Prefetch`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects). For example if you want to retrieve the `.values_list('id')`, you can prefetch that with:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

m = MyModel.objects.only("colA", "colB").prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'myManyToManyField',
        queryset=TargetModel.objects.filter(pk__gt=5),
        to_attr='filtered_pks'
    )
)
```

Then the `MyModel`s that arise from this will have an extra attribute `'filtered_pks'` here, that contains the `.filter(pk__gt=5)` of that related model. The `TargetModel` is thus the model to which the `ManyToManyField` refers to.

Comment: Went for a much simpler manual loop over .all(), but this thing of passing querysets to Prefetch is new to me, thank you for this!